# Android string split with regex to recieve LatLng

Tags: android, regex, split

guys i have below string:

```
lat/lng: (51.07459833333334,16.962598333333336)|lat/lng: (51.074299999999994,16.9628)|lat/lng: (51.07749999999999,16.9614)|lat/lng: (51.07770000000001,16.960998333333336)|
```

I try to convert it to LatLng Array. How to split this one?

Comment: String[] separated = CurrentString.split("|"); You can split each item by using the above code..

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes, split "|" is very simple but after this i don't know how to convert Array<String> to Array<LatLng>

Comment: use your logic there is no direct method...U got a string like this while splite lat/lng: (51.07459833333334,16.962598333333336) get the numbers from this by splite it again ...

Comment: post your code...

Comment: String coordString;
        List<String> coordL = new ArrayList<>();

        data.moveToPosition(ItemClickedPosition);
        coordString = data.getString(5);
        coordL = Arrays.asList(coordString.split(Pattern.quote("|")));
        coord = Arrays.asList(coordL);

Comment: and inside coordString is my string

Comment: @Nithinlal You'd need to escape that pipe when splitting, e.g. `input.split("\\|")`, but I think a formal pattern matcher would work better here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
    // Your string
    String strMain = "lat/lng: (51.07459833333334,16.962598333333336)|lat/lng: (51.074299999999994,16.9628)|lat/lng: (51.07749999999999,16.9614)|lat/lng: (51.07770000000001,16.960998333333336)|";
    strMain = strMain.replace("lat/lng: (", "");
    strMain = strMain.replace(")", "");

    String[] strLatLong = strMain.split("\\|");

    List<LatLong> latLongList = new ArrayList<LatLong>();
    for (String item: strLatLong) {
        String[] str = item.split(",");
        double latitude = Double.parseDouble(str[0]);
        double longitude = Double.parseDouble(str[1]);

        latLongList.add(new LatLong(latitude, longitude));
    }

    // Print List
    for (LatLong latLong: latLongList) {
        Log.d("LatLong", "Latitude: " + String.valueOf(latLong.getLatitude())
                + "\nLongitude: " + String.valueOf(latLong.getLongitude()));
    }
```

**Here is the dummy `LatLong` class:**

```
public class LatLong {

    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    public LatLong(double latitude, double longitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer D/LatLong: Latitude: 51.07459833333334
                                           Longitude: 16.962598333333336

com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer D/LatLong: Latitude: 51.074299999999994
                                           Longitude: 16.9628

com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer D/LatLong: Latitude: 51.07749999999999
                                           Longitude: 16.9614

com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer D/LatLong: Latitude: 51.07770000000001
                                           Longitude: 16.960998333333336
```

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem. You are man!:)

Comment: Most welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "lat/lng: (51.07459833333334,16.962598333333336)|lat/lng: (51.074299999999994,16.9628)|lat/lng: (51.07749999999999,16.9614)|lat/lng: (51.07770000000001,16.960998333333336)|";
List<LatLng> list = new ArrayList<>();

String pattern = "lat/lng: \\((.*?),(.*?)\\)\\|";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
int i=0;
while (m.find()) {
    double latitude = Double.parseDouble(m.group(1));
    double longitude = Double.parseDouble(m.group(2));
    list.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
}

// now convert the list to an array
LatLng[] array = list.toArray(new LatLng[0]);
```

Here is a link to a demo showing at least that the regex logic is working correctly:

## Rextester